# ¿Como hago un loop foreach con peticiones de tipo httpwebrequest en c#?

Tags: c#, webservice

Actualmente quiero enviar data de tipo xml a un ws que me han proporcionado y de hecho lo realiza pero solamente las primeras dos veces, después de eso se queda en espera o se detiene y ya no inserta el resto de los elementos.

```
    foreach (XmlElement nodo in doc.SelectNodes("request/entry"))
    {
        NodoReturn = "<request><entry>" + nodo.InnerXml + "</entry></request>";
        HttpWebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.Create("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx") as HttpWebRequest;
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("xxxxxx", "xxxxx");
        request.Timeout = 300000;
        request.ContentType = "application/xml";
        request.Accept = "application/xml";
        Encoding e = Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1");
        Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
        StreamWriter requestWriter = new StreamWriter(requestStream, e);
        requestWriter.Write(NodoReturn);
        requestWriter.Close();
        HttpWebResponse response;
        response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        requestStream = null;
    }
```

La linea en la que se detiene después de la segunda pasada es la siguiente:

```
 Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se debe a que no estás cerrando los streams que abres cuando realizas una petición al servidor, por eso se queda en espera:

Para evitar hacer esto manualmente se utiliza la palabra reservada [using](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement), una vez utilizado el objeto se destruye al terminar su utilización.

```
foreach (XmlElement nodo in doc.SelectNodes("request/entry"))
{
    NodoReturn = "<request><entry>" + nodo.InnerXml + "</entry></request>";
    HttpWebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.Create("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx") as HttpWebRequest;
    request.Method = "POST";
    request.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("xxxxxx", "xxxxx");
    request.Timeout = 60000;
    request.ContinueTimeout = 60000;
    request.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
    request.Date = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(1);
    request.IfModifiedSince = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(1);
    request.ContentType = "application/xml";
    request.Accept = "application/xml";
    Encoding e = Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1");

    byte[] bByteArray = e.GetBytes(NodoReturn);

    using (Stream sRequestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
    {
         sRequestStream.Write(bByteArray, 0, bByteArray.Length);
         sRequestStream.Flush();
         sRequestStream.Close();

         using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
         {
              using (Stream sDataStream = response.GetResponseStream())
              {
                   StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(sDataStream);
                   {
                        reader.Close();
                        sDataStream.Close();
                        response.Close();
                   }
              }
         }
    }

    request.KeepAlive = false;
}
```

Espero que te sirva.

Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Con cada iteración del ciclo estás reemplazando el request por una nueva instancia, por lo que, al ser un proceso asíncrono (es decir, no espera a la respuesta del servicio), posiblemente no haya regresado con el resultado cuando hacés la siguiente iteración del ciclo.

Esto lo podés resolver metiendo los requests en una colección de requests (puede ser una lista) y validando que todas las solicitudes recibieron respuesta al final del proceso.

```
List<HttpWebRequest> requests = new ArrayList<>();
...
requests.push(HttpWebRequest.Create("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx") as HttpWebRequest)
```

Y luego, iteras la lista de requests para asociar las funciones a ejecutar para capturar la respuesta de cada una de ellas, de forma individual. De esta forma, asignás a cada una de ellas su propio espacio en memoria, y pueden perfectamente estar activas de forma asíncrona y simultánea.